# Google Sheets - Track and Log highest value of other (dynamic) cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a sheet that imports a number to a cell (A2) via ImportXML. This value is always changing. Is there a script I can run that will, in another cell, track the highest realized value of A2, until a certain date, in B2?

Is this possible in Google Sheets?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score -1):

If you shared the code that you have it would be way easier to help you. Since I don't know your implementation I can only suggest pseudocode for you to try, but I (or anyone) can't tailor it to your case.

But basically you just need something like the code bellow just after you update the value of A2

```
if(a2<b2){
  b2=a2;
}
```